# Reverse a string through string class itself

Tags: java

I have a string let's say "saral". I want to reverse this string. 
How can it be done through string class itself?

Not through string buffer or string builder but only through string class.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - why?

Comment: (Please don't put random punctuation everywhere in your posts)

Comment: Loks like a typically dumb academia question to me, is this home work?

Comment: Yeah, no offense, but your question is missing a lot.  You haven't explained why, you haven't explained what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive function, something like:

```
public static String reverse(String in) {
   int pos = in.length() - 1;
   return pos == -1 ? "" : in.substring(pos) + reverse(in.substring(0, pos));
}
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks a lot, could you please replace the ternary operator with simple if else and then again can write this below piece of code, that will be a great help to undersatnd,..!!

Comment: @SARAL Can YOU replace the ternary operator with a simple if-else?  Since you know the name "ternary operator," I should hope YOU can!

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple, efficient way to do it since Java strings are immutable and they provide no `reverse()` method.  But you could build a reversed string by iterating the target string in reverse order and prepending the characters to a new string:

```java
public static String reverse(String source) {
  String target = "";
  for (int i=0; i<source.length(); i++) {
    target = source.charAt(i) + target;
  }
  return target;
}
```

Note that this is pretty inefficient because string concatenation (via the `+` operator) actually creates a StringBuffer under the hood, so you're allocating a bunch of temporary objects.

Comment: I think it's actually a `StringBuilder` under the hood these days, not that it makes much difference...